# Counting matches in array algorithm for song ratings

Tags: java, arrays

I've spent the last six hours trying to solve this small piece of code, and I really would appreciate learning how to do this.

I have this array so far:

```
public static void main ()
    {Song[] topTenSongs = {new Song("The Twist"), 
        new Song ("Smooth"),
        new Song ("Mack the Knife"),
        new Song ("How Do I Live"),
        new Song ("Party Rock Anthem"),
        new Song ("I Gotta Feeling"),
        new Song ("Macarena (Bayside Boys Mix)"),
        new Song ("Physical"),
        new Song ("You Light Up My Life"),
        new Song ("Hey Jude")
    };

    String[] tenSongNames = {"The Twist",
        "Smooth",
        "Mack the Knife",
        "How Do I Live",
        "Party Rock Anthem",
        "I Gotta Feeling",
        "Macarena (Bayside Boys Mix)",
        "Physical",
        "You Light Up My Life",
        "Hey Jude"};

        int [] songRatings = {2,8,10, 7,1,6,2,4,3,5};
```

My goal is to use a for-each loop to count the number of songs that are tied for second, and then to use a String variable and string concatenation to keep track of the Song titles tied for second.

How would I go about doing this? I currently have something along the lines of:

```
for (Song s : topTenSongs) {
    int count = 0;
    if(s.getRating() == 2) {    
        System.out.println(count + 1);
    }
}
```

but I have the feeling that this is wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately.

Comment: does your Song object contains rating as well ?

Comment: `String variable and string concatenation to keep track of the Song titles tied for second.` this is not clear, where do you need to save for tracking? and what?

Comment: @Deadpool I need to find the songs that both have rating of "2", which in this case would be songs in index 0 and index 7 in the array, and System.print.ln the titles of those songs. Those songs would be "The Twist" and "Macarena (Bayside Boys Remix).

Comment: @mkjh No, the Song object just includes the titles. I think that the rating is in a separate array called songRatings. Sorry if my terminology is off!

Comment: @MathyPerson then why are you calling s.getRating() ?

Comment: @MathyPerson added answer, let me know if that doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first iterate the  `songRatings` array the keep the track of index when `value==2`, an get song from `topTenSongs` array of that index

**for-loop**

```
 for(int i=0; i< songRatings.length; i++){
    if(songRatings[i]== 2){
       System.out.println("The song with rating 2 is :"+ tenSongNames[i]);
         // In the same way you can get songs from `topTenSongs` array of specific index `topTenSongs[i]`
          }
     }
```

If interested to learn java-8, by using `IntStream`

**java-8 IntStream**

```
IntStream.range(0, songRatings.length).filter(i->songRatings[i]==2).forEach(s->System.out.println(tenSongNames[s]));
```

**forEach**

```
int count =0;
for(int i: songRatings){
 count++;
  if(i==2){
    System.out.println("The song with rating 2 is :"+ tenSongNames[i]);
     }
   }
```

Comment: I'm curious about what this would look like as a for-each loop. How could I translate this for loop into that?

Comment: In foreach loop you will get value directly, but to keep index tracking you need a variable, i will add that also @MathyPerson

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in
`int count =0`
i should before the for. Because the count always come back to 2

Comment: fixed it to int count = 0. I'm not sure what to put between the if statement and the System.print.ln statement now, though.